# Allow IIS to Run a cmd command

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, process, iis-6

Building an ASP.NET MVC3 application at work and I'm trying to use a program that has to be started through a command prompt and passed arguments.

Currently I'm getting...

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied 
at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo) 
at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start() 
at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
```

This is only needed for one section of the website and I'm not sure what the best process would be to allow IIS (6) to accomplish this while maintaining security.

I don't think it's relevant, but just in case here is the code that I'm using to start the `Process()`

```
try {
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.FileName = @"C:\pdftohtml\pdftohtml.exe";
    startInfo.Arguments = "-c " + NewsletterPath + @"\" + fileName + ".pdf";

    Process.Start( startInfo );
} catch( Exception ex ) {
    return ex.ToString();
}
```

Question in a nutshell:

What is the best way to allow IIS6 to start a new Process that needs to pass arguments through a command prompt while maintaining security?

Comment: As a side note: it might be better to find a library that doesn't force you to spawn a new process. How many concurrent users do you expect?

Comment: This process is ONLY accessible from an internal user (or two).  It will only get used once a month (at most).  Basically we have a person that puts together a newsletter and I'm tired of having to all the conversions so I'm giving her web access and showing her how to do it... :)  Basically I'm lazy

Comment: I understand. mark though that this 'laziness' might lead to compromising the server's security. Any web worker running as ASPNET is now able to access the folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grant access to the user running IIS (Usually ASPNET) to the directory `c:\pdftohtml\`, that'll fix it.

Comment: You sir are my hero (for the moment).  Was banging my head against the wall!

Comment: @Jared: how is this done. I too am facing the same issue so how do add this permission?

Comment: @Shai: how is this done. I too am facing the same issue so how do add this permission?

Comment: @AJ, consult your system administrator, or just google "changing permissions on folders" +"windows <YOUR VERSION HERE">